# Hide Technology Usage

Tags: cms

Just out of curiosity. Is it possible hiding technology usage from website profiler, e.g: w3techs.com or builtwith.com? Information to be hidden such as Content Management System, Server Side Programming Language, Web Server. If possible, any negative influences? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## Hide

To hide this, you have to change the standard behaviour of the plattform.

For magento e.g. you have to hide the `js/varien/js.js` (and all the other files)

You have to hide the images are loaded from `/media`, the assets are from `/skin/frontend/package/theme/...`.

So I don'T think it is worth the time, to hide things.

## Show

Maybe you can trick the crawler, add a `wp-admin/wp-login.php` (?), or any other Typo3, Joomla, etc. typical content.

Comment: Thanks Fabian for the idea. I added those things but still failed to trick the crawler. I doubt there is a way to achieve this.